# Grant user from one domain permissions to shared folder in another domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, permissions, network-share

I have two computers set up like this:

- **\\myPC** (local Windows 7 SP1 machine); it is in *domain1*;
- **\\remotePC** (Win Server 2008 with SQL Server - a HyperV virtual machine); it is in *domain2*.

In *domain2* active directory, I have a user account *RemoteAccount*. I would like to give this account full permissions to a shared folder located on \\myPC, i.e. folder **\\myPC\SharedFolder**.

The problem is, when I right-click the folder and go to sharing permissions, I can't add permissions for the *domain2\RemoteAccount* user, because this user cannot be found - I can only see *domain1* users. When I click 'Locations' in "Select users, computers, service accounts, or groups" dialog, I only see *domain1*.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a [trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770299.aspx) between the two domains. At a minimum, a one-way trust where the domain that your computer is in must trust the other domain will need to be created.

Comment: This seems to be to the correct answer, but unfortunately it looks like I'm unable to create a trust - to do it, I'd have to be a _domain1_ administrator, which I'm not (I'm a local machine admin, but not a domain admin - and it fails to create a trust with these credentials).

Answer (score 0):

The only other options I can think of

1) create a local user with the same user name and password on each machine
2) Grant permissions on the folder (first try granting the user, if that doesn't work, try users or authenticated users).

The right way is to have a trust like it's mentioned although is more involved.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I would be very careful about recommending that people blindly use Users or Authenticated Users in ACLs if you don't know their exact requirements.

Comment: This person could run process monitor and find out exactly what user and grant permissions on that user or create a group and add that user within the group.